# Changing or Remap Mac ShortCut?

Tags: macos-high-sierra

Is there a way to easily remap mac shortcut, example i want to make:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to be up arrow key
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to be down arrow key
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to be left arrow key
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to be right arrow key

I tried using ukelele but it doesn't seems to work